# How i can make a get request to a php file from my custom plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a custom plugin for wordpress.
I need to make a `GET` request to a file to update information in the database, and redirect to the original page.

this the form

```
 <form action="" method="get">
                                
     <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $order->get_status(); ?>" name="status">
                               
   </form>
```

and i need to access a file in the same directory to update something

How do I start to accomplish what I requested?

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: You can not “make GET requests to files”, at most you can make one to a URL. But what you actually want here, is pretty unclear - you need to give us a better explanation of what you want to achieve here. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: is it clear enough now ??